# How to post data properly using a jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am posting some data to a PHP file using jQuery ajax like this:

```
$("#up-data").on("click", function(){
        var data= { 
            url : 'www.google.com', 
            product : 'KoKo' 
        };
        var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_custom.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
        }
});

        request.done(function( ) {
         console.log('Done');
        });
 
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }); 
    });
```

and on server side I have

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $u = $_POST["url"];
}
if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
    $p = $_POST["product"];
}


$_SESSION["product"] = $p;
$_SESSION["url"] =$u;
echo $_SESSION["url"] . "      ".$_SESSION["product"];
```

now I am getting

> Notice: Undefined variable: p in
> W:\wamp\www\WP\wp-content\themes\dev\session.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: u in
> W:\wamp\www\WP\wp-content\themes\dev\session.php on line 12

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your web console. maybe you do not send anything at all.

Comment: I am getting the `Done` from the `.done()` and with no error message

Comment: Try removing `.ajaxurl`, your code is correct

Comment: for debuging, insert in beforeSend alert(ajax_custom.ajaxurl +' '+ JSON.stringify(data)); whats the result ?

Comment: you have a comma in your url.. `url : www,google.com`

Comment: @Behseini You should do `function(response)` and `console.log(response);`  in your `.done()` function. Also, your code is working fine on my machine. Not sure why not on yours.

Comment: @FatFreddy Here is the resut on console `http://localhost/WP/wp-content/themes/Dev/session.php {"url":"www.google.com","product":"KoKo"}`

Comment: @vivek_23 I am getting `www.google.com      KoKo` when I console log the respone in `.done()`

Comment: @Behseini Then there is no issue at all. Where are you getting this error then?